# Calculate 500 digits of e

Tags: code-golf, math, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-time

Write a program to calculate the first 500 digits of the mathematical constant e, meeting the rules below:

- It cannot include "e", "math.e" or similar e constants, nor may it call a library function to calculate e.
- It must execute in a reasonable time (under 1 minute) on a modern computer.
- The digits are to include the 2 at the start. You do not need to output the `.` if you choose not to.

The shortest program wins.

Comment: What about \$(-1)^{1/i\pi}\$?

Comment: @Tbw I don't want to just ban a lot of things. If you want to use that please also give an answer that doesn't use any mathematical constants.

Comment: Since the output is always the same, can we hardcode the first 500 digits [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] style, or must the program use some formula to compute e?

Comment: @noodleman It would be great if you could calculate them. But can you really hardcode in fewer bytes than it would take to compute them?

Comment: Can I output a fraction where first 500 decimals in its expansion are the same as those of e?

Comment: @RubenVerg You have to output the digits.

Comment: Are we allowed to use the natural anti-logaritm?

Comment: May we output more than 500 digits?

Comment: @noodleman Just 500 digits please

Comment: @Adám. Isn’t the anti logarithm just e to some power?  I say no.

Comment: Regarding *"But can you really hardcode in fewer bytes than it would take to compute them?"*, in python using django.utils.baseconv.base62.decode it can get down to about 320 bytes (278 bytes for the data, plus about 40 bytes to import the decoding function and print)

Comment: @Stef Thanks. That looks like a no then.

Comment: Not sure what language would be good for golfing this, but I wonder if a solution based on the continued fraction expansion of e could work out.  From my scratch work, you need to take \$A := \prod_{n=1}^C \begin{bmatrix} 4n+1 & 2 \\ 2n+1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\$ for C sufficiently large, then take \$\frac{a_{11}}{a_{21}} + 1\$ to get a good approximation of e.

Comment: [Stop banning builtins](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13775/56656)

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 58 bytes

```python
x=10**499
print(x+sum((x:=x//i)for i in range(1,253))+128)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8LW0EBLy8TSkqugKDOvRKNCu7g0V0Ojwsq2Ql8/UzMtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VcNQx8jUWFNT29DIQvP/fwA)

---

Original version, before it was clearly specified that the decimal point could be omitted:

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 63 bytes

```python
x=10**499
print(f'2.{sum((x:=x//i)for i in range(2,253))+128}')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8LW0EBLy8TSkqugKDOvRCNN3Uivurg0V0Ojwsq2Ql8/UzMtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VcNIx8jUWFNT29DIolZd8/9/AA)

Comment: This is really great!

Comment: Remove the f-string to shave off 1 byte: https://www.online-python.com/yPGKEzH6lV

Comment: @vengy No, that's 3 bytes longer.

Answer (score 14):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 11 bytes

```
1∆ȯ1∆ṡ+500Ḟ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCIx4oiGyK8x4oiG4bmhKzUwMOG4niIsIiIsIiJd)

Calculates cosh(1)+sinh(1) to 500 decimal places.

```
1∆ȯ         # cosh(1)
      +     # + 
   1∆ṡ      # sinh(1)
       500Ḟ # to 500 decimal places
```

Comment: »nor may it call a library function to calculate e«

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 This isn't calling a library function that explicitly calculates e. It's calling two distinct functions that, both evaluated at 1, happen to sum to e.

Comment: It calculates with library functions, the challenge says »nor may it call a library function to calculate e« and not »nor may it call a library function that calculates e«. This is arguably a bad rule, since you are not allowed to use any library functions to do any calculation to calculate e, and it isn't very clear what a library function is and what not, but i didn't made the rules.

Comment: A better constraint on this problem would be to not use a library function which calculates any value based on the exponential function. Since cosh is defined as (e^x+e^(-x))/2 and sinh is (e^x-e^(-x))/2 I would argue it's still calling a library function which calculates the exponential function, and therefore not valid.

Comment: @Hossmeister Du kannst Sinus hyperbolicus auch als unendliche Summe aus der Taylorreihe definieren ohne auf die Exponetialfunktion zurückgreifen zu müssen. Naja, eine Regel die gewisse Funktionen verbietet sind meist schwammig.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes

```python
n=x=z=499
while~-n:x=(x+10**z)//n;n-=1
print(f'2.{x}')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8@2wrbK1sTSkqs8IzMntU43z6rCVqNC29BAS6tKU18/zzpP19aQq6AoM69EI03dSK@6olZd8/9/AA)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 44 bytes

Outputs *e* without the `.`, courtesy of [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor).

```python
n=x=z=499
while n:x=x//n+10**z;n-=1
print(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8@2wrbK1sTSkqs8IzMnVSHPqsK2Ql8/T9vQQEuryjpP19aQq6AoM69Eo0Lz/38A)

Comment: The challenge now allows you to omit the decimal point, so you can just use the [unshifted version](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8@2wrbK1sTSkqs8IzMnVSHPqsK2Ql8/T9vQQEuryjpP19aQq6AoM69Eo0Lz/38A "Python 3 – Try It Online").

Answer (score 8):

## R, <s>104</s> 90 bytes

Since R doesn't have arbitrary precision arithmetic, and other answers already have used the limit definition and Taylor series of *e*, I use a decimal spigot algorithm to spice things up. I don't usually write loop-based code in R, so there is plenty of room for improvement. (`divmod` would be useful).

-7 bytes thanks to pajonk's better looping, and another -7 because I remembered R's colon operator can go backwards.

```r
C=rep(1,254)
d=2
for(i in 1:500){cat(d)
d=0
for(j in 254:2)C[j]=(t=10*C[j]+d)-(d=t%/%j)*j}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGCpaUlaboWN6OcbYtSCzQMdYxMTTS5UmyNuNLyizQyFTLzFAytTA0MNKuTE0s0UkBSBmCpLJAUULGVkaZzdFasrUaJraGBFoipnaKpq5FiW6Kqr5qlqZVVC7EBahHMQgA)

Based on [*The Calculation of e to Many Significant Digits* by AHJ Sale (1968)](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article/11/2/229/378761?login=true). The basic idea is to use an \$m\$th order Taylor polynomial, extract an integer part and fractional part, multiply the fractional part by 10, and repeat on the fractional part. Here's an example extracting the first decimal digit using 4 terms: (the 0 coefficients are coincidence)

\begin{alignat}{4}
\newcommand\pp{\phantom{0}}
e 
&\approx 2 + {} && \biggl[  &\frac 1 2 \biggl(\pp1 + {} 
  &&\frac 1 3 \biggl(\pp1 + {} &\frac 1 4 (\pp1) \biggr) \biggr) \biggr]\\
&= 2 + \frac{1}{10} && \biggl[  &\frac 1 2 \biggl( 10 + {} 
  &&\frac 1 3 \biggl( 10 + {} &\frac 1 4 (10) \biggr)  \biggr) \biggr]\\
&= 2 + \frac{1}{10} && \biggl[  &\frac 1 2 \biggl( 10 + {} 
  &&\frac 1 3 \biggl( 12 + {} &\frac 1 4 (\pp2) \biggr)  \biggr) \biggr]\\
&= 2 + \frac{1}{10} && \biggl[  &\frac 1 2 \biggl( 14 + {} 
  &&\frac 1 3 \biggl(\pp0 + {} &\frac 1 4 (\pp2) \biggr) \biggr) \biggr]\\
&= 2 + \frac{1}{10} && \biggl[7 + {}  &\frac 1 2 \biggl(\pp0 + {}
  &&\frac 1 3 \biggl(\pp0 + {} &\frac 1 4 (\pp2) \biggr) \biggr) \biggr]
\end{alignat}

<sup>Thanks to Steven B. Segletes for helping with MathJax formatting.</sup>

I believe the integers involved never exceed \$10m\$. The fractional part is always less than 1, so the computed digit can't affect the previous digit. \$e\$ is special because the coefficients of the Maclaurin series of \$e^x\$ are all 1. Trig functions for \$\pi\$ would have larger coefficients or produce negative digits, which would require amending previous digits. For example, here's Newton's arctan formula for \$\pi\$:

\begin{align}
\frac \pi 2 
&\approx 1 + \frac 1 3 \biggl( 1 + \frac 2 5 \biggl( 1 + \frac 3 7 (1) \biggr) \biggr) \\
&= 1 + \frac 1 3 \biggl( 1! + \frac 1 5 \biggl( 2! + \frac 1 7 (3!) \biggr) \biggr) 
\end{align}

There is no clean way to transform \$\frac 3 7 (10)\$ into an integer part while the fractional part is a multiple of \$\frac 3 7\$ and less than 1. The solution is modifying the spigot to maintain held *predigits* that are released once we are sure the digits are correct. See [*A Spigot Algorithm for the Digits of π* by Rabinowitz and Wagon (1995)](https://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/amm_supplements/Monthly_Reference_12.pdf).

\$m\$ can be calculated beforehand from the error of the finite sum using Stirling's approximation. For \$n+1\$ correct digits, find least \$m\$ satisfying \$m! > 10^{n+1}\$, equivalently
$$\frac 1 2 \ln(2\pi m) + m(\ln m - 1) > (n+1) \ln 10$$

Ungolfed algorithm:

```r
n = 500
m = 254
C = rep(1,m)
cat(2)
for(i in 2:n){
  d = 0
  for(j in m:2){
    t = 10*C[j] + d
    d = t %/% j
    C[j] = t - d*j
  }
  cat(d)
}
```

Comment: If it works in Algol 60, it works in R!

Comment: [Some golfs for -7 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGCpaUlaboWNxOdbYtSCzQMdYxMTTS5UmyNuNLyizQyFTLzFAytTA0MNKuTE0s0UkBSBlxZtkBVXOUZmTmpGhpZtlm6hpp2hprO0VmxtholtoYGWiCmdoqmrkaKbYmqvmqWplZWLcQiqH0wewE) (without actually trying to understand the algorithm, so further improvements are possible).

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 25 bytes

```
Sum[1/k!,{k,0,∞}]~N~500
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P7g0N9pQP1tRpzpbx0DnUce82tg6vzpTA4P/AUWZeSUKDun//wMA)

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 29 bytes

```
Limit[(1+1/n)^n,n->∞]~N~500
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773yczN7MkWsNQ21A/TzMuTydP1@5Rx7zYOr86UwOD/wFFmXklCg7p//8DAA)

Comment: `Tr[1/Range@260!]~N~500` would win by 1 byte, except it calculates \$e-1\$ isntead of \$e\$!

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51 bytes (-2 thanks @xnor)

```
m=p=~2**3333
exec"m=m*m/~p;"*3333
print-m*10**499/p
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWN41zbQts64y0tIyBgCu1IjVZKdc2VytXv67AWgkiWFCUmVeim6tlaKClZWJpqV8A0Qo1AWYSAA)

#### former [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```
p=4000
m=2**p+1
exec"m=m*m>>p;"*p
print`m*5**p`[:500]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWN00LbE0MDAy4cm2NtLQKtA25UitSk5VybXO1cu3sCqyVtAq4Cooy80oScrVMgQoSoq1MDQxiIZqhZsDMAgA)

Outputs the digits as a single string, no decimal point.

### How?

Approximately computes \$(1+1/n)^n\$ for \$n=2^{4000}\$ using repeated squaring.

Comment: Looks like `p=~2**m` works

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9c2wNZIS8vEwMCAqzwjMydVIdfGSCvAKtc2VytXP0DbkKugKDOvRCFXy9AAqMzSUj/g/38A "Python 2 – Try It Online"). Might be possible to do shorter by sticking to powers to 10, [something like this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9nW0EBLy9TAgCvPNlkrWduQK7UiNVkpzzZPS8vQQD8ZSFpYKwGZQBUFRZl5JQp5@sn//wMA "Python 2 – Try It Online").

Comment: @xnor Thanks. I now found quite a few 51s but nothing better.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 100 bytes

```python
from decimal import*
getcontext().prec=500
e=d=Decimal(1)
for x in range(2,254):e+=1/d;d*=x
print(e)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Nc1LCsIwEADQfU6RZVJ_bbFQlOy8SMlMasBkwjBCPIubbvRO3sZFdf_gPd_lIVfKy_K6S9iNHwhMSQP6mKabjqkQS6NmFE9ZsIqx-8Lo3dC2Ch24yypNZ1Ug1lXHrHnKM5p-2w9He8KN6w5whsZVVThmMWjX61f-6y8)

-2 bytes thanks to [RubenVerg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/118045/rubenverg)

254 is the lowest number which gives the correct result, but this doesn't get slow until you start looping for thousands of iterations.

This uses the definition:

\$ \displaystyle e = \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1 \cdot 2} + \frac{1}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3} + \cdots \$

The only optimization used is to instead of calculating the factorial of each n from 1 to 254, we store the factorial of \$ n-1 \$ in the variable `d`, and each iteration multiply d by the loop number `x`.

This uses the Python's decimal library with `getcontext()` in order to calculate the number to 500 digits of precision.

Comment: change the range to start from `2` and you don't need the `-1` in the last line

Comment: @RubenVerg Nice idea!

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
≔⁰θＦ⊖φ≔÷⁺Ｘχ⁴⁹⁹θ⁻φιθ2.Ｉθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBCsIwEEX3nmLoagaiRHFTuhK7cVHIFUI66kBMaBLb48cWxeXnv/fc0yYXra/1krM8AmoFE3W7e0yAPbvELw6FRzxqrYngR91C6WWWkdH4d0YTF04rouDctrQVFAwS1mfTFAjRN2uShILN6dD8x9XmghNRV2vdz/4D) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⁰θ
```

Start with a running total of `0`.

```
Ｆ⊖φ≔÷⁺Ｘχ⁴⁹⁹θ⁻φιθ
```

For each integer from `1000` down to `2`, add `10**499` to the running total, then divide by that integer. This is equivalent to summing the reciprocals of the factorials from `2` to `1000` but without any loss of precision.

```
2.Ｉθ
```

Output `e` to `500` digits.

20 bytes to output without the decimal point:

```
≔⁰θＦφ≔⁺Ｘχ⁴⁹⁹÷θ⁻φιθＩθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DQEehUNOaKy2/SEHD0MDAQFMBKhGQU1qsEZBfnloEFNdRMLG01NRR8Mwrccksy0xJ1SjUUfDNzAMqAWnSUcjU1NSEmBRQlJlXouGcWFyiUaipaf3//3/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: As above but counts down to `1` and also adds the `10**499` after dividing so that the result includes the `0!` and `1!` terms.

Answer (score 5):

## C, <s>126</s> <s>116</s> 109 bytes

Port of [my R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269079/17360).

-10 bytes by rearranging loop logic printing leading 2, inspired by pajonk, and some small optimizations.

-7 bytes by using `C` with zeros instead of ones, credit
chux - Reinstate Monica. Previously, the initialization of array `C` to 1s is a GNU extension.

```c
i=500,d=2,j,t,C[255];main(){while(i--){putchar(d+48);d=0;j=254;while(j-->2)t=10*C[j]+d+10,d=t/j,C[j]=t%j-1;}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6FjdzM21NDQx0UmyNdLJ0SnSco41MTWOtcxMz8zQ0q8szMnNSNTJ1dTWrC0pLkjMSizRStE0sNK1TbA2ss2yNTE2sIUqydHXtjDRLbA0NtJyjs2K1U7QNQWaW6GfpgPi2JapZuobWtbUQS6F2w9wAAA)

Comment: Great to see a C answer. +1

Comment: Maybe `C[]={[0 ...255]=1}` --> `C[256]` and `t = 10 * C[j] + d + 10, d = t / j, C[j] = t % j - 1;` or something along the lines of uses a zero'd `C[]`.

Comment: @qwr Shave off 3 bytes using for()'s instead of while()'s
`i=500,d=2,j,t,C[255];main(){for(;i--;putchar(d+48),d=0,j=254)for(;j-->2;)t=10*C[j]+d+10,d=t/j,C[j]=t%j-1;}`


[example](https://tio.run/##HczdCgIhEEDhpwk0Z0hlhUDsZh9DvBBlN4f@2Iwuoldvars88HEKzqUwt@C0hhosEHQYo3Uu@XNuFyFf03URviH626OXY15EVcNe/rAGCtYN8g8I8WC97MHo7RgpqarMeuw7grVD3xAa/2bmmD5lOuX5zvj8Ag)

Comment: Building on @vengy [101 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/T1tTAQCfF1kgnS8c52sjUNNY6NzEzT6NEszotv0jDOlNX1zrFVrGgtCQ5I7FII0XbxEJTJ8vWyNREEyyfpatrZ2TtHJ0Va1uimqVrqFlim6JraKBVBxICmluin2Vd@///v@S0nMT04v@65QA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: If you don't mind possible undefined behavior, define C[] (compiler assumes to have one element) and then rely upon the adjacent memory as usable space. [98 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/T1tTAQCfF1kgnS8c5OtY6NzEzT6NEszotv0jDOlNX1zrFVrGgtCQ5I7FII0XbxEJTJ8vWyNREEyyfpatrZ2TtHJ0Va1uimqVrqFlim6JraKBVBxICGlqin2Vd@///v@S0nMT04v@65QA).

Comment: Is that adjacent memory always zeros?

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES11), 45 bytes

*-5 thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)*

A port of [Neil's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269035/58563), as suggested by Neil himself.

```javascript
f=(q=i=999n)=>i?f((q+10n**499n)/-~i--):"2."+q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVaj0DbT1tLSMk/T1i7TPk1Do1Db0CBPS8sEJKSvW5epq6tppWSkp6Rd@D85P684PydVLyc/XSNNQ1PzPwA)

Comment: 57 using recursion instead of a for loop [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFbCoAgEADAu/jlq1qDfoKts4RlGLKbGeHtbebavq34J95vR7wfrQWUGR3ZiNlWdEBaTzCSwqWuQWaDdUBjoo22qlmMvTB5cABAzTMVTkef@JRBKtV@ "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: You can save a byte by swapping the order of arguments `q` and `x`, and doing `q+x` instead of `q+=x`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAv3hy02wVugRbb4nKMGTNjPD3NnOt31q2J9xvz2k/WvMkK1nkrhvRsc4UyDLQXBcv60BKBZ1VhUk4I1QeLCJy2xKXFA8T0ym9BGg/ "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: You can save at least two bytes by porting my method instead.

Comment: [45](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVaj0DbT1tLSMk/T1i7TPk1Do1Db0CBPS8sEJKSvW5epq6tppWSkp6Rd@D85P684PydVLyc/XSNNQ1PzPwA)

Comment: @l4m2 This is why I said "at least". (I had `f=(i=252n,q=0n)=>--i?f(i,(q+10n**499n)/-~i):"2."+q` but obviously the same trick applies.)

Answer (score 4):

## APL (NARS2000), 20 chars = 40 bytes

```
499⍕+/5 6x○≢⎕FPC←1E4
```

`⎕FPC←1E4` set Floating Point Control to use ten thousand bit floats

`≢` count that (gives 1)

`5 6x○` compute sinh and cosh of that (while indicating with `x` that we want extended precision)

`+/` sum

`499⍕` output with 499 decimals, i.e. 500 digits in total

Answer (score 4):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 29 bytes

```
2 4000:a?:b){.*b/}a*5a?*+500<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/30jBxMDAwCrR3ipJs1pPK0m/NlHLNNFeS9vUwMDm/38A)

Ports [Albert.Lang's wonderful Python 2 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269058/108687) to GolfScript. Check that answer for a better understanding of the math.

Code explanation:

```python
2 4000:a?:b)
2 4000        # Push 2, 4000 to the stack.
      :a      # Store 4000 in variable a.
        ?     # Power; 2 ^ 4000
         :b   # Store 2 ^ 4000 in variable b.
           )  # Add one.

{.*b/}a*5a?*
{             # Open a block:
 .*           # * Duplicate and multiply (squaring
              #     the top of the stack.)
   b/         # * Integer divide by b.
     }a*      # Run this block a times.
        5a?   # Push 5 ^ a.
           *  # Multiply.

+500<
+      # Append this result to the implicit input,
       #   which is the empty string, therefore
       #   coercing the number to a string.
 500<  # Leave just the first 500 characters of
       #   this string.
```

### [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 30 bytes

```
"2."128 10 499?{2+/.@+\}251,/;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X8lIT8nQyELB0EDBxNLSvtpIW1/PQTum1sjUUEff@v9/AA)

Based on m90's Python solution, since GolfScript has big integers but no floats.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ȷ⁵*;R:\SDḣH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///E9keNW7Wsg6xigl0e7ljs8f8/AA)

A Jelly version of [m90’s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269032/42248). This is a niladic link which returns the first 500 digits of e as a list of decimal digits.

### Explanation

```
ȷ           | 1000
 ⁵*         | 10 ** this
   ;R       | Concatenate to 1..1000
     :\     | Reduce using integer division, collecting intermediate results
       S    | Sum
        D   | Decimal digits
         ḣH | First 500 (since half of 1000 is 500)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 110 bytes

```
252*
L$`_
$>`,_
^
2.¶
749{`$
;
(_*);(_*)
10*$1$2;
¶(_+),(\1)*(_*);
;$#2*_¶$1,$3
)`^(.*)(¶.*);(_*)
$1$.3$2
1G`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYuxDUIxDAX7twYubBNF2GmQIv2WhhHQdygoaCgQHXtlgCwWPkg019zd8/a6P642J@xwVJypBWhpKbDC8@hwK@9GqOBQqV9spZKRV4zOsZfEFxP9aVTaucboZIkKpK2cVXj0/H@3MRdy2KnN@QE) Too slow to produce 500 digits on TIO so link just produces 108. Explanation: Port of @qwr's R answer.

```
252*
L$`_
$>`,_
```

Generate the working array. (Note: This is an estimate of its size, but increasing it just requires additionally increasing the iteration count of the loop below to compensate.)

```
^
2.¶
```

Start with `2.`.

```
749{`
)`
```

Loop 749 times, which produces 499 digits for some reason.

```
$
;
```

Start another parallel iteration.

```
(_*);(_*)
10*$1$2;
```

Multiply each value by 10 and add the carry from the next element's previous iteration.

```
¶(_+),(\1)*(_*);
;$#2*_¶$1,$3
```

Divmod each value by its index and propagate the carry to the previous element for its next iteration.

```
^(.*)(¶.*);(_*)
$1$.3$2
```

Generate the next digit from the first element.

```
1G`
```

Remove all of the elements leaving just the final decimal expansion.

Answer (score 2):

## APL(NARS), 76 chars

```
Q;r;d;k;v;⎕FPC
r←d←1⋄k←÷10x*501⋄v←0x
r+←d×←÷v+←1⋄→2×⍳k<∣d
⎕FPC←4×501⋄⎕←499⍕r
```

14+21+20+18+3=76

Calculus in rationals, and print with 499 digits after the point (499+1=500) the last digit rounded
(but not changed because the 500th digit after the point should be 2<6)

```
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535475945713821785251664274274663919320
  0305992181741359662904357290033429526059563073813232862794349076323382988075319525101901157383418793070215408
  9149934884167509244761460668082264800168477411853742345442437107539077744992069551702761838606261331384583000
  7520449338265602976067371132007093287091274437470472306969772093101416928368190255151086574637721112523897844
  250569536967707854499699679468644549059879316368892300987931
```

Comment: You are printing 501 digits

Comment: @Tbw it seems are printed 500 digits after the point

Comment: 499 instead of 500 in function show the number

Comment: Your APL answer has to beat my C answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), 26 bytes

```
N[Sum[1/k!,{k,0,∞}],500]
```

[Try it on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5BSum%5B1%2Fk%21%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D%2C500%5D)

Comment: This is actually 26 bytes because `∞` is a 3-byte character for Mathematica.

Comment: @infinitezero Removed the E. Thanks.

Comment: the TIO result printed 21 extra digits, plus `\`500` at the end.

Comment: @qwr removed the TIO test, not sure why it was corrupted like that.

Comment: I think TIO may be running WolframScript, which doesn't do natural language I/O like WolframAlpha. (For example, you can type "first 100 primes" into WA but it won't run as Mathematica code.)

Comment: `N[Sum[1/k!,{k,0,∞}],500` funktioniert auch, das fehlende `]` wird von WolframAlpha automatisch angenommen.

Comment: Oder `N[i^(-2i/pi),500`

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 17 bytes

```
Cosh@1+Sinh@1`500
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zm/OMPBUDs4Mw9IJZgaGPwPKMrMK1FwSP//HwA) A direct port of [emanresu A's nice answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269030/56178).

Comment: OP said in comments that Exp function isn’t allowed, fyi

Comment: Ok thanks—I only looked in the post itself.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
₅L₄°šÅ»÷}O₄;£
```

Port of [*@NickKennedy*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269056/52210), which in turn is based on [*@m90*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269032/52210), so make sure to upvote those answers as well.

Outputs the first 500 digits as a single concatted integer.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOrz6OmlkMbji483Hpo9@Httf5ArvWhxf//AwA)

**Explanation:**"

```python
₅L             # Push a list in the range [1,255]
  ₄°š          # Prepend 10**1000
     Å» }      # Cumulative left-reduce, keeping intermediate results
       ÷       #  by doing integer-division
         O     # Sum all those results together
          ₄;   # Push 500 (1000 halved)
            £  # Keep only the first 500 digits
               # (after which this integer is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 89 bytes

A port of [@m90's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269032/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sODkxJ9F4R7SSbk5iXnppYnqqVUF-cUlaZoV_QbFS7M78pKzU5BIF38TMPIXUipLUvJRiBceCAoXqpaUlaboWNyPLEosUKmydMtM980o0DA00FQryyxVMLC25Cooy80py8jSKlYz0VKo1oCoMNPWtNIwUSvIVjEyNNDU1NIp1MjUVbO2Ktasr9G0zrStqNbUNjSxqlTQhFiyshdALFkBoAA)

```scala
var x=BigInt(10) pow 499
println(s"2.${(BigInt(0)/:(2 to 252))((s,i) =>s+{x/=i;x})+128}")
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU-9DgFBGOw9xUQUuxGHRYJQ0ClUohLFur-srD3Z3fMTuSfRaHgnvQex51b3zXzzfTNzf5mQS957PJ65TVrD9yfb7ePQYsmFwq0GRHGCgwOE69SMMdOaXzcrq4VKt3SMtRIW058SOHGNi0NzkS6UJd0ODY7ZmfRHI-r3Ejo2uSxPSJJpEIFJCww2AxswiquIZeS_VfpInJz4gjaEZ0sHx3r0nwoamPyAJrps-COOLqKVipg6CxqVa72MUdSKqquv_K_-BQ)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var x = BigInt(10).pow(499)
    val result = (for (i <- 2 to 252) yield {
      val div = x / i
      x = div
      div
    }).sum + 128
    println(s"2.$result")
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## SageMath, <s>20</s> 18 Byte

Sehr unkreativ:

```
n(i^(2/i/pi),1664)
```

Alte Antwort:

```
n((-1)^(-i/pi),1664)
```

[Onlinetest](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzL09DQNdSM09DN1C_I1NQxNDMz0QQAMugEuQ==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

`i^(2/i/pi)` =e :
`e^(πi) = -1` => `e^(πi/2) = i` => `e = i^(2/πi)`

`n(....)` : Kontentiere zu Dezimal

`1664` : Mit einer Genauigkeit von 1664 bit

Comment: Moin. Willkommen. Es gibt keine Regel, die vorschreibt, dass Antworten auf Englisch erfolgen müssen, aber Fragen müssen und auf Englisch bekommt man eine bessere Reaktion.